# IPtables used for load balancing

Tags: iptables

I am trying to use iptable for load balancing.
The rule I have set is as follows wherein I want to route requests coming to my server with ipaddress 10.x.x.4 to internal ips of the server 10.x.x.1:1010 , 10.x.x.2:1010 and 10.x.x.3:1010

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.1:1010

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.2:1010

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp -d 10.x.x.4 --dport 1010 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.x.x.3:1010
```

When I execute , the first 4 packets gets routed to each ipaddress correctly.
The 5th packet doesn't get routed and is getting dropped.

How do I debug this issue. Should I increment to value given to --packet ? What should be the correct rule?

Comment: Not a question for SO. Try [sf] or [unix.se]

Comment: @sm_view, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27397989/3903832) answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You should increment --packet from 0 to n-1 in each command line. Where n is the number given as the parameter to --every.