# Simple load balancing using iptables nth mode of the statistics module

Tags: iptables

I am trying to use `iptables` for load balancing. I'm working with `virtualbox`. All VMs (`debian`) are in an internal network and IPs are static.  I want to route requests coming to my web server (`apache2`) with IP address `10.0.0.2:80` to IP addresses of the servers `10.0.0.3:80` and `192.168.0.2:80` on the other network. The network is constructed as such:
The gateway does IP forwarding, it has two interfaces: `eth0` used for network `10.0.0.0` and `eth1` for network `192.168.0.0`. Then there is a load balancer with IP address `10.0.0.2`. I've tried to set these rules but they didn't work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.3:80    
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:80
```

Comment: This is probably a question for serverfault instead of SO.

Comment: Ask this question on serverfault.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, since in your case the incoming connection should be distributed across 2 servers, one would have expected a similar solution to the one suggested, but with `--every 2`, rather than `--every 3`, to work.

However, as [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/491517) suggests, when the `nth` mode was made part of the `statistic` module (in the past it was a separate module), the packet counter was modified from a global one to many individual ones, one per rule.

Therefore, the following should work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.3:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:80
```

Of course there is no actual need for use of the `statistic` module in the second rule, but I've placed it there for future reference in order to clarify how the rules should be constructed if the incoming connections were to be distributed across 3 or more servers, rather than just 2.